# form fields all required using html5 required parameter not working

Tags: html

Hi I am trying to make all the fields in my form required,

I am using the required parameter and adding it to all the fields but its not working at all, not showing any validation error

```
<form action='index.php' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

<h6>First Name</h6>
<input type='text' name='fname' value="First Name" required /> 

<h6>Last Name</h6>
<input type='text' name='lname' value="Last Name" required /> 

<h6>Email</h6>
<input type='text' name='email' value="Email" required /> 

<h6>Password</h6>
<input type='text' name='password' value='Password' required /> 

<input type='submit' value='submit' />
<input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted' /> 

</form>
```

Comment: Where is your `<form>` tag and submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation of `required` fields occurs only after you try to submit a form. The problem with the posted code is that there is no form wrapped around the inputs, therefore there is no form to submit.

This is how you should've done it:

```html
<form action="#">
  <h6>First Name</h6>
<input type='text' name='fname' required /> 

<h6>Last Name</h6>
<input type='text' name='lname' required /> 

<h6>Email</h6>
<input type='text' name='email' required /> 

<h6>Password</h6>
<input type='text' name='password' required /> 

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

If, however, you want instant validation, you'll have to do it yourself using one of many validation libraries which already exists or by writing custom JavaScript code.

Comment: @jdoe1991 then please post the whole code, not just a part of it. Also, if you run the code, you'll see that the validation is working. If you want more, then read the last paragraph of my answer, after the code.

Comment: code posted, no i just want the fields to be required before submitting the form

Comment: What exactly is not working? Keep in mind that you've already set a `value` to the fields, I hope you know that this automatically makes them valid since the only validation of `required` `[type=text]` fields is the field is not empty. If you want to display some explanation for the field, use `placeholder` property.

Answer (score -1):

Input tags are self-closing.  The "/" is the first suspect.  Try it again without those closing tags.  I would also remove the space after "required", but that's just my OCD.

Comment: Also, check out using <label>'s for your input elements instead of <h6></h6>.  They're cool, because when a user clicks on the label, the cursor jumps to the correlating input field.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: All of this is irrelevant. It's still valid HTML, at least according to HTML5 standards. I agree with using labels for the most part, but there might still be a reason to use `h6` from the design standpoint, although it would be odd and would probably mess with the accessibility.